# Object items are not rendering (Object is stored in an array of objects which in turn is stored in a React state hook)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

My problem is that item stored in object (in an array of objects inside a state hook) is not being rendered on page, but it gets printed with `console.log`

I fetched some data from the server and it worked as expected, returning an array of two items, one of which is an object containing blog data(blog heading, creator, etc) an another is an array of 'sections' of that blog. Here is how I did it,

This is the initialization

```
// Get the blog id
const {blog_id} = useParams();

// Declaring our state hooks
const initial_blog_state = {
    blog_id: blog_id,
    heading: '',
    creator: {},
    created: '',
    section: [],
}
const [blog_state, updateBlogState] = useState(initial_blog_state);
```

Here is the fetching of data from the server

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Fetching data
    Promise.all([
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blog/${blog_id}`),
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/section/full/${blog_id}`)
    ]).then(responses => {
        // Get a JSON object from each of the responses
        return Promise.all(responses.map(response => {
            return response.json()
        }))
    }).then(function (data) {
        // Log the data to the console
        console.log(data);

        // Update state
        updateBlogState({
            ...blog_state,
            heading: data[0].heading,
            creator: data[0].creator,
            created: data[0].created,
            section: data[1]
        })
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // if there's an error, log it
        console.log(error);
    }); 
}, []);
```

I think the way I'm updating the section inside the hook can be a problem(although I'm not sure how), because I saw in a stackoverflow answer that objects must always be initialized (which I'm not doing when declaring an array of 'objects')

And here is the thing that needs to be rendered

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        <h1>{blog_state.heading}</h1>
        <p className="text-small text-muted">{blog_state.creator.username}</p>
        {blog_state.section.map(item => {
            {console.log(item.paragraph)}
            <p>{item.paragraph}</p>
        })}
    </div>
)
```

Here `blog_state.heaing` and `blog_state.creator.username` are being rendered as desired and also `console.log(item.paragraph)` prints the correct paragraph on the console window, but `item.paragraph`  doesn't show anything on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is being returned from your map.

i.e you need to add a return line before the `<p>{item.paragraph}</p>`

So:

```
        {blog_state.section.map(item => {
            console.log(item.paragraph)
            return <p>{item.paragraph}</p>
        })}
```

or as an inline return:

```
        {blog_state.section.map(item => <p>{item.paragraph}</p>)}
```